# Rewrites with has param cookie type break images

Tags: next.js

**next.config.js**

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */

const has = {
  type: 'cookie',
  key: 'mobile',
  value: 'true',
};

module.exports = {
  publicRuntimeConfig: {
    API_URL: [process.env.API_URL]
  },
  trailingSlash: true,
  images: {
    domains: [process.env.API_URL,
    deviceSizes: [640, 750, 828, 1080, 1200, 1920, 2048, 3840],
  },
  webpack: (config, { isServer }) => {
    if (!isServer) {
      config.resolve.fallback = {
        fs: false,
      };
    }

    return config;
  },
  async rewrites() {
    return {
      beforeFiles: [
        {
          source: '/path,
          destination: '/mobile/path',
          has: [has],
        },
        {
          source: '/path/:league/',
          destination: '/mobile/path/:league/',
          has: [has],
        },
        {
          source: '/:url*/',
          destination: '/mobile/:url*/',
          has: [has],
        },
      ],
    };
  },
};
```

Above you can see my `next.config.js` , there you can find `rewrites` function ,  which detect to which destination , should it be moved . I want to make it work by `cookie` . But it breaks my `Image` . And it breaks it particularly for `cookie` has type. I've checked it with `query` type

```
const has = {
  type: 'cookie',
  key: 'mobile',
  value: 'true',
};
```

and it works perfectly. What do I mean by "breaks my image" , it means that

[image]

images shown like on image above, I was thinking , maybe  `rewrites` cause some changes in url , but url exactly the same ..  url path

```
http://localhost:3000/_next/image/?url=https://external-url.com
```

I want to understand is it some bug on `next` , or do I have to add smth to `next.config.js` to fix it

Also , important to mention , when I go directly on `/mobile/path` , not to `/path` where rewrite happens , images also works

Also opened discussion [here](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/37909)